# Error extracting element from an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array like this

```py
a = np.array(1)
```

Now if I want to get 1 back from this array, how do I retrieve this?

I have tried

```py
a[0], a(0)
```

but they give error:

```
IndexError: 0-d arrays can't be indexed
```

or

```
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

I even tried to do some weird flattening but I am pretty sure that it shouldn't be that complicated. I am getting errors in both. All I want is that 1 as an int?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

What you create with

```
a = np.array(1)
```

is a zero-dimensional array, and these cannot be indexed.  You also don't *need* to index it -- you can use `a` directly as if it were a scalar value.  If you really need the value in a different type, say `float`, you can explicitly convert it with `float(a)`.  If you need it in the base type of the array, you can use `a.item()` or `a[()]`.

Note that the zero-dimensional array is *mutable*.  If you change the value of the single entry in the array, this will be visible via all references to the array you stored.  Use `a.item()` if you want to store an immutable value.

If you want a one-dimensional array with a single element instead, use

```
a = np.array([1])
```

You can access the single element with `a[0]` now.

Comment: I'm adding a search term here: nditer. I haven't worked much with numpy yet so I got stuck with nditer providing me 0-d arrays rather than the objects. Anyway, thank you for the solution!

Comment: You CANNOT use it as it was scalar value because it is not a scalar value. Using it directly (for example, appending the "value" to a list) may result in unexpected errors, because you are still using the reference to the original array and if it changes its value, it is also changed wherever you used the reference (such as the list in my example).

Answer (score 0):

You can also call `tolist()` or any of the array reducer functions such as `max()`, `sum()` etc. on `a`.

```py
a = np.array(1)

a.tolist()  # 1
a.max()     # 1
```

One thing to note, however, is that they don't all return the same object because if you check their types, `a.item()`, `a.tolist()` etc. return a Python type while operations using the array itself (`a.ravel()[0]`, `a.max()` etc.) return a numpy dtype. For example,

```py
a = np.array(True)
b = np.array([True])

type(a.tolist())      # bool
type(a.max())         # numpy.bool_

a.tolist() is True    # True
a.max() is True       # False

a.tolist() is b[0]    # False
a.max() is b[0]       # True
```